# To stop reload data of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

How to stop reload data of UITableView when scrolling up and down?

Comment: Well I dont think that is a good thing to do..

Comment: uitableView so it has to be ios..

Comment: I know this is not good idea, but its my app requirement, if you know then plz tell me...

Comment: I'm not going to recommend this in any way but you can use the UIScrollViewDelegate methods (UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView) to set the UITableView's delegate to nil and back when scrolling events are called.

Comment: I meant datasource of course... Setting the delegate to nil would make it so you don't receive the delegate calls of uiscrollview.

Comment: Alas its not working properly, actually i am getting data from xml and display on table view via custom cells, so when i scroll it down above data hide and when i scroll up hide data display but again waiting for response from server for xml, so i do not want this my requirement is if data show tableview then it should save or remain there. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

A UITableView implements lazy loading. It means, that the OS loads only what you see. So, if you are scrolling up or down in a table view, the OS will load those cells. Note, that the OS reloads each cell at each appearance. This means, when you create your UITableView, not each cell of the table view will be loaded, only the visible ones. When a cell disappears after scrolling, and reappears after scrolling back, it will be reloaded again.